# JBoss Seam cancel request with a button

Tags: button, jboss, timeout, seam

I have an application with requests which fetch lists from huge tables (7 mil+ records) that can take up to 10 seconds to complete.

Is there any way to have a `cancel` button to cancel the request instead of waiting for the previous request to finish.  Currently, if the user tries clicking the `cancel` button (a page redirect), then it will throw a `ConcurrentRequestTimeoutException`.

I could increase this timeout, as it is now set to `500 ms`, but then the user would have to wait for the previous request to complete.  I want it to cancel the previous request and redirect immediately.

Is this possible?

Button code:

```
<s:button id="cancelEdit" value="Cancel" propagation="end"
  view="/reference/ProviderList.xhtml">
</s:button>
```

I also tried using h:commandButton and ending the conversation before-redirect in the page.xml file.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Leave the conversation behind by putting an actionListener="#{conversation.leave}" attribute on your cancel button. If you have a  add a propagation="none" attribute instead.

Comment: Sorry, I forgot to add these details.  I have updated my post. But yes, I tried ending the conversation both with the button propagation above and ending in the page.xml before-redirect. I don't think it would matter that I'm using end instead of none, would it?

Comment: There is a big difference between ending(propagation=end) a conversation and leaving it(propagation=none). Ending merely makes a long running conversation a normal one (reuse the same conversation id). Leaving it leaves the conversation in the background and starts a new one. By the way, I've tested the propagation=none on your use case and works perfectly. Just ending the conversation doesn't solve the problem.